# Express 4 route handling with named parameters and router.param()

Tags: node.js, express

Is there a clean way to handle key/value query params in Express 4 routes?

```
router.route('/some/route?category=:myCategory')
```

I want to detect the presence of 'myCategory' in this route and use router.param([name], callback) to handle the associated logic.

```
router.param('myCategory', function(req, res, next, id) {
    /* some logic here... */
});
```

The above 'router.param()' works fine if I have a route like `/some/route/:myCategory` but fails if I use

```
router.route('/some/route?category=:myCategory')
```

Am I doing something wrong here, or is this not supported in the Express 4 router out of the box?

Answer (score 2):

Express treats properties after a `?` as query params. So for:

`/some/route?mycategory=mine`

you would have to use:

`req.query.mycategory` or `req.query['mycategory']`

See this for more [examples](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.query).

Comment: So using `router.param()` is not possible for query params in that case?

Comment: General rule of thumb: `/route/:param` and `/route?query=val`. And based on the [docs](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router.param) for `router.param()`, I want to say no.

Comment: I'll add that RESTfully, it probably makes more sense to for you to do `/route/:mycategory` and reserve query params for optional fields. A common example is `/route/MyCat?startPage=0&endPage=1` illustrating paging. Hope that helps.

Comment: It's unfortunate that `router.param()` will not work here.   I was hoping to use it for parameter validations.   I know there's ways to do it without `router.param()` but it would have been nice and clean.  Oh well, thanks for the help, Tony!